# Error : Inserting values from other table via variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

This is my query :

```
set @agent_id = select agnt.id from agent agnt , session ses 
where ses.session_id = '0021a7ca-6e' and ses.employee_id = agnt.employee_id ;

insert into inquiry_placed_by(inquiry_id , agent_id) values(1 , @agent_id);
```

This error i get :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select agnt.id from agent agnt , 
session ses where ses.session_id = '0021a7ca-6e' at line 1
```

Is this kind of operation is possible in mysql or am i missing something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first two lines:

```
set @agent_id = (
select agnt.id from agent agnt , session ses 
where ses.session_id = '0021a7ca-6e' and ses.employee_id = agnt.employee_id ) ;
```

Comment: i get this error : #1048 - Column 'agent_id' cannot be null

Comment: This syntax works perfectly fine in SQL Server.

Comment: It must be because you are being returned with a null value

Comment: and your table "inquiry placed by" wont be accepting any null value in agentID as you may have marked that column not null explicitly

Comment: you are correct , my query returned null value. I tested it on valid data and it's working fine.Thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for which brackets are used?

Comment: Yes, the reason is the syntax... often you learn such things by trial and error!

Comment: accepted it and one vote up.cheers.